# Starting and stopping services on remote Linux servers

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I am in the middle of creating a game server control panel and i have a few issues.

The control panel needs to basically issue commands to a remote Linux server, starting and stopping processes, i have the commands written for this, however the problem is.

1. I am not sure whether to just SSH in using a PHP library and then issue the commands OR have remote files on the server to deal with this. Which would be most efficient?
2. Is it even safe running SSH commands from PHP, using the root account? Even if commands that will be sent are hard coded.
3. If the remote Linux servers would need remote files, what language would this be written in and what functions are best?

If you have any other ideas of the best way around this, please share, i will be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. that is possible but only done in special occasions. Usually the simpler way is to use some form of reqeust protocol, like for example http and thus evoke predefined routines (scripts) on the servers side. What protocols does the server speak?
2. NEVER DO THAT ! Usually that would mean to grant root access inside ssh which is unsafe. you could also use something like sudo or suid bits, unsafe again. And you would even top that by send the commands, since that would mean your setup would ahve to acceppt any command it is given and execute it under root rights. Not a good idea...
3. Use any language that is available on the server and that you feel comfortable with. Does it really matter what language you use to express what you want to say? No, the content matters. Maybe the coice also depends on what type of access you chose. Some languages offer themselves more easily in certain situations.

In short: without more detailed informations only a vague answer is possible.

Comment: The commands that are ran are not user defined, but already coded into the system, would that make it okay?

Comment: Granting root access via ssh never is a good idea. And I understood that passage "commands being sent" such that they are not stored on the system itself, but meant to be sent via ssh too. So the service interface you plan to provide will execute code given to it from outside as root. Ouch.

Comment: Noooo, the user has three buttons, stop/start/restart. The commands for these buttons are already there and cannot be changed.

Comment: I don't understand that. If those 'commands', the buttons are already on that server, what do you need ssh for? I guess they ae on some other system, so you are looking for a way to remotely execute these commands on the server. In that case the commands are external code given to the server, no matter if they are interactively typed or stored in some file. Try to think from the servers point of view. He does not know who connects...